# Different cross entropy results from NumPy and PyTorch

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

My prediction is `y_hat = [ 0.57,0.05,0.14,0.10,0.14]` and target is
`target =[ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]`.

I need to calculate Cross Entropy loss by NumPy and Pytorch loss function.

Using NumPy my formula is `-np.sum(target*np.log(y_hat))`, and I got `0.5621189181535413`

However, using Pytorch:

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
output = torch.FloatTensor([0.57,0.05,0.14,0.10,0.14])
label = torch.FloatTensor([1,0,0,0,0])
loss_value = loss(output, label)
print(loss_value)
```

Gives `tensor(1.2586)`, which is different.

Comment: Please don't completely change the wording and meaning of a question, especially after you've gotten an answer. If you have a new question, please ask it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) to your `y_hat` vector before computing cross-entropy loss. For example, you can use [`scipy.special.softmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.softmax.html).

```py
>>> from scipy.special import softmax
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y_hat = [0.57, 0.05, 0.14, 0.10, 0.14]
>>> target =[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> y_hat = softmax(y_hat)
>>> -np.sum(target * np.log(y_hat))
1.2586146726011722
```

Which agrees with the result from Pytorch.